# What is wrong with my plant , how I can save it?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

I need your help to save this plant , I water it when the soil is just dry, I don't know what is the disease

Comment: Hi Shady, welcome to the site.  We do need a lot more information to be able to help you.  Such as where in teh world you are, what sort of plant, a photo of it, etc.  Please edit teh question to provide the information.

Comment: Welcome! Without knowing what plant we are talking about and what symptoms you perceive, this is unfortunately not answerable. Please [edit] your post and we can reopen the question. A photo would be very, very helpful, and highly recommended, otherwise you would have to write quite a bit of explaining text.